# How to traverse an ExpandoObject and get specific values

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, expandoobject

I have the following XML
(part)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<definition date="2021-04-30" version="1.01">
    <changes>
        <change number="1" date="2021-04-30" description="Added .." />
        <change number="2" date="2021-04-30" description="Changes in .." />
        <change number="3" date="2021-04-30" description="Fixed .." />
        <change number="4" date="2021-05-11" description="Added " />
    </changes>
    <general>
        <styles>
            <style name="title">
                <font name="Arial" size="12" bold="true"/>
            </style>
            <style name="general">
                <font name="Courier new" size="10" bold="true" />
            </style>
            <style name="header">
                <font name="Courier new" size="10" bold="false" />
            </style>
        </styles>
    </general>
```

I'm using Dandraka XML-Utilities to make the XML an ExpandoObject. Which should allow me to get easily to specific values. For instance, working with the above I am able to get the Definition date and version like this:

```
    Dim strXML As String
    strXML = File.ReadAllText("C:\Tools\ReportDefinitions.xml")
    Dim def As Object
    def = XmlSlurper.ParseText(strXML)
    Console.WriteLine(def.date)
    Console.WriteLine(def.version)
```

However, I'm having a hard time getting any deeper.
Tried all the ones that are commented out

```
'error For Each c In def.changes                    'unable to cast
'error For Each member In CType(def.changes, IDictionary(Of String, Object)) 'Invalid cast
'error For Each c In def.change                     'missing change
'error For Each c In def.changes.change             'missing change
'error For Each c In def.definition.changes.change  'missing definition
'error Console.WriteLine(def.changes.change(0).number)  'missing member
'Console.WriteLine(def.changes.changelist.numner)
For Each member In CType(def.changes, IDictionary(Of String, Object))
  Console.WriteLine(member.Key)
Next
```

This is what the def variable looks like
[image: Local variables]

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Specifically iterating through the changes.

Comment: You are late-binding based on member name.  So to iterate the list of changes in `def`: `For Each change As Object In def.changes.changeList`.

Comment: Ah, @TnTinMn I see now where I went wrong. The changeList is with an uppercase L. Thought I already tried your example but must have worked with a lowercase 'l'.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by @TnTinMn. Used the wrong casing. This is how it works

```
    For Each change As Object In def.changes.changeList
      Console.WriteLine(change.number)
    Next
```