# How to search in generic list of ExpandoObject

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, expandoobject

Following up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525597/how-to-traverse-an-expandoobject-and-get-specific-values). I am now trying to find a specific occurrence of an XML-part.  For instance in the following XML
(part)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<definition date="2021-04-30" version="1.01">
    <changes>
        <change number="1" date="2021-04-30" description="Added .." />
        <change number="2" date="2021-04-30" description="Changes in .." />
        <change number="3" date="2021-04-30" description="Fixed .." />
        <change number="4" date="2021-05-11" description="Added " />
    </changes>
    <general>
        <styles>
            <style name="title">
                <font name="Arial" size="12" bold="true"/>
            </style>
            <style name="general">
                <font name="Courier new" size="10" bold="true" />
            </style>
            <style name="header">
                <font name="Courier new" size="10" bold="false" />
            </style>
        </styles>
    </general>
```

I would like to find change number 3.
I'm using Dandraka XML-Utilities to make the XML an ExpandoObject. Which should allow me to get easily to specific values. For instance, working with the above I am able to get the Definition date and version like this:

```
    Dim strXML As String
    strXML = File.ReadAllText("C:\Tools\ReportDefinitions.xml")
    Dim def As Object
    def = XmlSlurper.ParseText(strXML)
    Console.WriteLine(def.date)
    Console.WriteLine(def.version)
```

I would like to use Linq on the list: def.changes.changeList. But simply:

```
def.changes.changeList.where(Function(c) c.number = "1").count()
```

Gives an error on the `where` part. Have searched here on SO but most examples are in C# and translating them to VB.net ends up in something that doesn't compile.
Suppose I have to Cast it but how?

In C# was able to use Linq with this:

```
            var iet = def.changes.changeList;
            var iets = (IEnumerable)def.changes.changeList;
            var iets2 = iets.Cast<dynamic>();
            var iets3 = iets2.FirstOrDefault(p => p.number == "3");
            int iets4 = iets3.number;
            Console.WriteLine(iets4);
```

Now in VB.Net I can do most of it like this:

```
    Dim iet As Object = def.changes.changeList
    Dim iets = CType(def.changes.changeList, IEnumerable)
```

But this line:

```
            var iets2 = iets.Cast<dynamic>();
```

No idea how to transform that to VB.Net..

Thanks

Comment: `dynamic` is how you make C# let you do late binding.  I think the equivalent in VB would just be `Cast(Of Object)`.  Note that `IEnumerable.Cast(Of T)` will give you an `IEnumerable(Of T)` from an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Hi John, I only just saw this question. I'm the owner of the library, happy to hear it's useful :-) Did the reply from Marco cover you? If yes, I'll it as a VB.Net example when I release a new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Dandraka XML and found you an answer. The issue is that Linq does not work on just IEnumerable but needs something like `IEnumerable<T>`. So if you cast the changeList to the type `List(Of Dandraka.XmlUtilities.ToStringExpandoObject)` then you can use Linq on that. In the Linq function there is another cast to Object so we can access the dynamic properties.

```
Dim def = XmlSlurper.ParseText(File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\data.xml"))
Console.WriteLine("Definition date " & def.date.ToString)
Console.WriteLine("Definition version " & def.version.ToString)
Console.WriteLine()
Dim list As List(Of Dandraka.XmlUtilities.ToStringExpandoObject) = def.changes.changeList
Dim number3 As Object = list.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) CType(i, Object).number = "3")
Console.WriteLine(number3.date.ToString & " - " & number3.description.ToString)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about Dandraka XML which is probably a way to convert xml to objects. I would not go there, but instead use the normal `System.Xml` library to read the contents and find what you need using XPath. So this is not an exact answer, but more like an alternative answer to get the same result.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("c:\temp\data.xml")
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
Console.WriteLine("Definition date " & root.Attributes("date").Value)
Console.WriteLine("Definition version " & root.Attributes("version").Value)
Console.WriteLine()
Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("changes/change[@number='3']")
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes("date").Value & " - " & node.Attributes("description").Value)
```

This will get you the following output

```
Definition date 2021-04-30
Definition version 1.01

2021-04-30 - Fixed ..
```

See also:
[select nodes using xpath navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation)